# Save image as file in a folder on the server

Tags: php, image, save

I have this code running...

```
$im = imagecreatefromstring($arr['IMAGE']->load());
$result = $arr['IMAGE']->load();

echo $result;

exit();
```

and this code is showing the image on the browser. My question is...how to save as a file and save on the server?

I am using this code and it is saving as a file but there isn't a image.

```
define('UPLOAD_DIR', 'testuploads/');
// $img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $result);
// $img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
$data = imagejpeg($result);
$file = UPLOAD_DIR . uniqid() . '.jpeg';
$success = file_put_contents($file, $data);
print $success ? $file : 'Unable to save the file.';
```

Comment: `$im = imagecreatefromstring($arr['IMAGE']->load());` appears to be redundant. What was the purpose of this line? Did you mean to do `imagejpeg($im);` later on? Also check http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php - it returns true or false, not data. You have to specify the output target as a parameter. RTM.

Comment: if you have some more code please edit the question with it instead. Anyway it still won't work because of what I mentioned about the return type of imagejpeg. Did you read the documentation before writing this code?

Answer (score 1):

use imagejpeg($result, $file) or imagepng if it is a png, instead of file_put_contents.

(where $result is your img, and $file your path+file name)

EDIT: see doc: http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php

example:

```
<?php
// Create a blank image and add some text
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(120, 20);
$text_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 233, 14, 91);
imagestring($im, 1, 5, 5,  'A Simple Text String', $text_color);

// Save the image as 'simpletext.jpg'
imagejpeg($im, 'simpletext.jpg');

?>
```